# bootable usb ubuntu 22.04 stuck on "Welcome to GRUB"

Tags: usb, 22.04

Have an old HP Pavilion DV7 without UEFI. Trying to install an Ubuntu 22.04 it stuck at the beginning of booting "Welcome to GRUB". Can somebody help with advice, or salvation.

Comment: How much RAM? Specs say upgradeable to 4GB. Full Ubuntu works best on newer systems with over 4GB of RAM. You may want to try a light weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I was able to install Kubuntu which is more of a mid-weight flavor on a very old system which surprised me that it worked reasonable well.

Comment: RAM is 8GB, thank you for advice i`ll try those light weights.

Comment: If 8GB that should be plenty for Ubuntu. I just have to like Kubuntu.

Comment: Tried everything, may be it has something to do with switchable GPUs. Because on boot and Welcome to GRUB appears, the cooler of laptop is reeving. Found this solution url: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-installation-40/slackware64-14-2-usb-stick-boot-stuck-at-welcome-to-grub-and-a-cursor-4175678525/, but did not understand anything

Comment: What GPUs?  Show in question above: `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12`

Comment: Here is the shared screenshot: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLAXM5mwmw4gYVpTBHxBoOUpbya3K_7g/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: I do not know AMD, but you show the correct i915 driver for Intel & Radeon driver for your AMD card. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver That should be correct. Are you booting live installer with Safe Graphics? Or in BIOS setting only have internal gpu working so install works.

Comment: I making an bootable USB with Rufus(tryed all settings dd mode, ISO mode, UEFI CSM, without UEFI just BIOS) and using ubuntu 22.04.iso, selecting my USB stick on boot and then it stuck on "Welcome to Grub" and my laptop cooler starting spin. just like an when i installing ubuntu 20.04 witch loads ok. I tryed to push F8 on loading BIOS to make it display Safe Mode Menu, but it is not appearing. Tryed to turn off dynamic GPU switch, tryed to turn it off using fixed GPU :))

Comment: It still seems to not be seeing USB drive & then going to old grub on internal drive which will not boot. Try a different USB port, or a different USB flash drive.

Comment: i have a 4 USB plugs, two of them are USB 3.0 and other two are regular USB. I think i will try to make a bootable DVD. I will feed back, first need to find one DVD now a days

Comment: Got it installed with an bootable DVD UBUNTU 22 on it. Thank you alot @oldfred for advices and help :)